# Multiplication table specific formatting using C++

Tags: c++, loops, formatting, do-while, multiplication

My teacher is asking for a specific format for this program that I've written in regards to multiplication tables. I have finished the rest of the program and it has been tested and works well so far, the only issue is that I need to match the exact format she requested but I'm having trouble doing so.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int num;
char selection;

do
{

cout << "MENU\n";
cout << "a) Generate Multiplication Table\n";
cout << "q) Quit the program\n";
cout << "Please make a selection: ";
cin >> selection;


if (selection == 'a' || selection == 'A') {

    cout << "Please enter a number for your multiplication table: \n";
    cin >> num;


    while(num < 1 || num > 10)
    {
    cout << "Invalid Selection\n";
    cout << "Re-enter a number between 1 and 10\n";
    cin >> num;
    }

    cout << '\n';
    cout << "MULTIPLICATION TABLE: " << num << "'s\n";
    cout << '\n';

    for (int row = 1; row <= num; row ++)
    {
        cout << setw(2) << row << "|";

        for (int col = 1; col <= num; col ++)
        {
            cout << setw(3) << col * row << "| ";
          //  cout << setw(3) << row << "     "

        }
        cout << endl;
    }



}


else if (selection == 'q' || selection == 'Q') {

    cout << " You have chosen to quit the program. Thank you for using!\n";
}

/*else if (selection != 'a' || selection != 'q')
{
    cout << "Invalid Selection\n";
    cout << '\n';
    cout << "MENU\n";
    cout << "a) Generate Multiplication Table\n";
    cout << "q) Quit the program\n";
    cout << "Please make a selection: ";
    cin >> selection;
}*/

 }while (selection != 'q');
}
```

The multiplication table after printed should look something like this: It contains --- and |

[image]

One last issue is that I'm trying to figure out how to print out the numbers on top as shown below. There are duplicates going horizontally of the numbers 1-7. I can't seem to figure out how to do it without a for loop because the the numbers should be printed from 1- the users input but the spacing just doesn't work correctly and I'm not sure if that is the proper way to do it.

My output looks as follows (it looks more precise in code format): MULTIPLICATION TABLE: 7's

```
 1|  1|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|   7| 

 2|  2|   4|   6|   8|  10|  12|  14| 

 3|  3|   6|   9|  12|  15|  18|  21| 

 4|  4|   8|  12|  16|  20|  24|  28| 

 5|  5|  10|  15|  20|  25|  30|  35| 

 6|  6|  12|  18|  24|  30|  36|  42| 

 7|  7|  14|  21|  28|  35|  42|  49|
```

I will post the text output as well just in case:

MULTIPLICATION TABLE: 7's

```
 1|  1|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|   7| 

 2|  2|   4|   6|   8|  10|  12|  14| 

 3|  3|   6|   9|  12|  15|  18|  21| 

 4|  4|   8|  12|  16|  20|  24|  28| 

 5|  5|  10|  15|  20|  25|  30|  35| 

 6|  6|  12|  18|  24|  30|  36|  42| 

 7|  7|  14|  21|  28|  35|  42|  49|
```

Comment: When you used a debugger, which line was causing the issue?

Comment: Please append your output, as text, to your question.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews There wasn't a specific line the only issue was just matching the output with that formatting. I'm pretty sure you'd have to tweak around the for loop but every time a single change is made it throws off the whole format. I'll attach my output right now

Comment: If you run the debugger, you will see which line of your code causes the problem.  If you attach your output, maybe we can find the problem sooner.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN The output has been attached.

Comment: After "cout<<endl", before end of loop, you should try the "---|---|..."  Is this the only thing missing?  I don't see it in your code?

Comment: Oh ... you mean how to print the column headers.  Do that before your for loop.  I would do a simple for loop to produce a single line of the dashes-and-bars.

Comment: Yes that is the only thing I am missing I just couldn't figure out the correct placement for it. This is what that turns out to be: 
 1|  1|   2|   3|   4|   5| 
---- |  2|  2|   4|   6|   8|  10| 
---- |  3|  3|   6|   9|  12|  15| 
---- |  4|  4|   8|  12|  16|  20| 
---- |  5|  5|  10|  15|  20|  25|
It didn't work pretty much because I'm not sure if you can see the proper format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74151/discussion-between-douglas-o-moen-and-jean-claude-hasrouty).